# Z-Buffer algorithm vs Painter's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

In hidden surface removal, how does the Z-buffer algorithm work vs. painter's algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short painter's algorithm can't deal with intersecting geometry.

Suppose that you draw a plane angled away from the camera, and a plane angled towards the camera. The planes intersect in an 'X' shape.

```
Camera ------> X
```

With painter's algorithm no such ordering exists that will render the shape exactly. You would only see whichever plane you decided to draw last.

The Z-Buffer or Depth-Buffer stores the nearest depth per each pixel relative from the camera. If another triangle is rasterized and has a depth less than the current depth buffer value it is accepted, if it's depth is greater, it is rejected. This is called a depth test.

Comment: The painter's algorithm can also fail with nonintersecting geometry if there are cycles in the occlusion relation. For example, consider three rods arranged on the ground in a triangle such that each rod is resting on the one clockwise from it. Viewed from above, there is no rod that can be drawn first.

Comment: Painter's algorithm *WILL* work with overlaps etc provided you take the steps described by Newell, Newell & Sancha.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newell%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 5):

- In the **painter's algorithm**, you first sort all graphics elements
  on depth (deepest first) and
  then one-by-one fully paint them into the image on top of each other.
  That way, deeper elements are obscured by less deep element.
  (Intersecting graphics element require special attention.)
- In the **depth-buffering algorithm**,
  you store the current depth of each pixel in the image
  (in addition to other pixel info),
  and fully paint each graphics element pixel-by-pixel,
  where an image pixel is updated
  only if its depth is more than that of the new pixel.

So, there is a time-memory tradeoff:

- The **painter's algorithm** requires an extra sorting step (**costs time**),
  but avoids storing additional (depth) information per pixel (**saves memory**).
- **Depth-buffering** avoids sorting (**saves time**),
  but stores extra (depth) information per pixel (**costs memory**).